# How to interrogate Iterator state in Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iterator

I'm sure I'm just not seeing a button, and am just searching with all the wrong keywords.  This must be simple...

Example: in Chrome,

1. Hit F12
2. Go over to Sources and hit pause
3. Go to the console, enter `var x = [1,2,3,4].entries(); x.next();`
4. Step through the assignment statement and hover over `x`
5. You see a tooltip showing `x` is a Array Iterator, and you can expand the prototype.  No internal state seems to be buried here.

I want to know where the Iterator is at, and what data it's accessing.  Its internal state seems to be hidden.  How can I find this?

Comment: it is all laid out [right here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-iterable-interface).

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm not a lawyer, that isn't useful

Comment: My guess is you're an EE based upon your NPN avatar :-) - Iterator objects only track the next index to be provided by the `.next()` method of the Iterator interface. It is stored internally and you do not have access to it. Besides, if you wanted access to the internal state of the iterator, then you wouldn't need the iterator at all - there would be no use case for the interator.